# What rules do I need to enforce each method parameter on a new line with CheckStyle and Closing parenthesis and Opening method bracket on a new line

Tags: java, checkstyle

I've been working in a new package that has an unusual coding style and no way to enforce it. For example:

```
public void doSomething(
        String foo,
        Integer bar
) {
    // do stuff
}
```

and

```
public void doSomething(
) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I've looked at all the CheckStyle rules here http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html and nothing really pops out as providing that capability

I'm trying to enforce style rules like:

1. Parameters start on line following method name
2. One parameter per line
3. Closing parenthesis for parameters and opening bracket for method body
   are on the same line

Is anyone aware of a set of rules that would allow me to enforce this or have an idea on how to implement a way to enforce this style?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using intellij

Answer (score 2):

> Parameters start on line following method name
>   One parameter per line
>   Closing parenthesis for parameters and opening bracket for method body are on the same line

There is no check in Checkstyle that will validate and enforce what you want.

> how to implement a way to enforce this style

The best way is to create your own check in a 3rd party jar for Checkstyle. Most of your requirements have to do with 2 tokens not appearing on the same line So, all you need to do is find the tokens you are interested in and check their line position relative to each other and produce a violation when warranted.

I recommend reading the following:
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html#Usage_by_Classpath_update

If you are successful with your check(s), you might want to consider posting them at https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle .